# when returning json data from webservice top tag is adding <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Hi  every one  when returning json data from webservice top tag is adding   please let me know how to remove top xml tag in the webservice
 please let me know if any one this issue

i used the below method read

var obj = new List();

```
    //MakesInfo objMakes = new MakesInfo();
    MakesBL objMakesBL = new MakesBL();

    if (Session["Makes"] == null)
    {
        obj = (List<MakesInfo>)objMakesBL.GetMakes();
        Session["Makes"] = obj;
    }
    else
    {
        obj = (List<MakesInfo>)Session["Makes"];
    }
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();


    //var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    //string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(obj);

    //return sJSON;

    //yourobject is your actula object (may be collection) you want to serialize to json
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<MakesInfo>));


    //create a memory stream
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    //serialize the object to memory stream
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
    //convert the serizlized object to string
    string jsonString = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    //close the memory stream
    ms.Close();
    return jsonString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WCF just return list json object data is returned